# How to make geometry point in CnosDB_2.4?

Tags: cnosdb

I have a data set that has timestamp, latitude and longitude columns, and I was confused after I load that data into cnosdb for geometrycalculating 。

```sql
create table source_data_table(x double, y double, tags(ori));
insert into source_data_table(time, ori, x, y) values
  ('2023-10-01T00:00:00', 'tx_01', 1.0, 2.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:00:00', 'tx_02', 33.0, 65.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:01:00', 'tx_01', 3.0, 3.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:01:00', 'tx_02', 30.0, 55.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:02:00', 'tx_01', 4.0, 3.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:02:00', 'tx_02', 50.0, 50.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:03:00', 'tx_01', 5.0, 4.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:03:00', 'tx_02', 66.0, 45.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:04:00', 'tx_01', 6.0, 5.0),
  ('2023-10-01T00:05:00', 'tx_02', 67.0, 33.0);

select * from source_data_table;

+---------------------+-------+------+------+
| time                | ori   | x    | y    |
+---------------------+-------+------+------+
| 2023-10-01T00:00:00 | tx_02 | 33.0 | 65.0 |
| 2023-10-01T00:01:00 | tx_02 | 30.0 | 55.0 |
| 2023-10-01T00:02:00 | tx_02 | 50.0 | 50.0 |
| 2023-10-01T00:03:00 | tx_02 | 66.0 | 45.0 |
| 2023-10-01T00:05:00 | tx_02 | 67.0 | 33.0 |
| 2023-10-01T00:00:00 | tx_01 | 1.0  | 2.0  |
| 2023-10-01T00:01:00 | tx_01 | 3.0  | 3.0  |
| 2023-10-01T00:02:00 | tx_01 | 4.0  | 3.0  |
| 2023-10-01T00:03:00 | tx_01 | 5.0  | 4.0  |
| 2023-10-01T00:04:00 | tx_01 | 6.0  | 5.0  |
+---------------------+-------+------+------+
```

How to transfer that list into `'Point(x, y)'`s, such as `st_makepoint(x, y)`:

```sql
select time, st_makepoint(x, y) from source_data_table where ori = 'tx_01';

422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Invalid function 'st_makepoint'.\nDid you mean 'date_bin'?"}
```